# Synonomize [google-materials-design] and [material-design]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

[google-materials-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-materials-design) and [material-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-design) are basically the same thing. They currently are not synonyms. Should they be merged, synonomized, or the less-active one deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 of the 21 questions tagged with [google-materials-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-materials-design) were also tagged with [material-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-design). I've removed the [google-materials-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-materials-design) tag from these 16.

The [material-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-design) tag appears to be the main tag. It has 128 questions and a tag wiki (compared with [google-materials-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-materials-design) which now has only 5 questions and no tag wiki).  I think it would make sense for the tags to be established as synonyms with [material-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-design) as the main tag.

Comment: I've tried to, but it seems that I have to wait for other mods to approve it.  Thanks for bringing it to our attention.